# ZIO STM not mutating

Tags: stm, zio

This prints out the unchanged value of `5`:

```scala
import zio.stm._
import zio.Console
import zio.Runtime.{default => rt}

class TInt(n: TRef[Int]):
  def ++(): USTM[Unit] = n.update(_ + 1)
  override def toString: String = n.toString

object TInt:
  def make(n: Int): USTM[TInt] = TRef.make(n).map(TInt(_))

class Client:
  val stmN: USTM[TInt] = TInt.make(5)
  def increment: USTM[Unit] = stmN.flatMap(_.++())

val c = Client()
rt.unsafeRun(for
  _ <- c.increment.commit
  n <- c.stmN.commit
  _ <- Console.printLine(n)
yield ())
```

How can I (w/ minimal *structural* changes) get it to print out the incremented value instead? With some testing, I know that `TInt` is solid. The issue, I suspect, has to do w/ `Client.stmN` being a `USTM` and not *reflecting* the underlying mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undressed `stmN: STM[TInt]` and now it's simply `n: Tint` and being tracked as a constructor parameter. This requires construction of the `Client` to be pulled into, effectively, a `TRef.map`:

```scala
import zio.stm._
import zio.Console
import zio.Runtime.{default => rt}

class TInt(n: TRef[Int]):
  def ++(): USTM[Unit] = n.update(_ + 1)
  override def toString: String = n.toString

object TInt:
  def make(n: Int): USTM[TInt] = TRef.make(n).map(TInt(_))

class Client(val n: TInt):
  def increment: USTM[Unit] = n.++()

object Client:
  def apply(): USTM[Client] = TInt.make(5).map(new Client(_))

rt.unsafeRun(for
  c <- Client().commit
  _ <- c.increment.commit
  _ <- Console.printLine(c.n)
yield ())
```

The effect of this is that `c` is now part of the returning value w/in `unsafeRun`. Seems like `Client` needed to be wrapped w/ a `USTM` in order for its mutability to be taken seriously. In general, it is best, I have found, to not spread transactions amongst various classes w/in composition trees. While it does make for a nice OO design, it makes it difficult to get the mutability desired. Instead, try to keep everything on the same class and just use `stm.T`* as the state.